# how to set the default time in elasticsearch 6.2.1

Tags: elasticsearch

`_timestamp` has been deprecated, [reference documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/breaking_50_mapping_changes.html#_literal__timestamp_literal_and_literal__ttl_literal) says we should have our own fields which will have time, how we set the default value to current timestamp fields in milliseconds in ElasticSearch 6.2:

```
{
    "properties":{
        "defautlt_time":{
            "type":"date",
            "default_value":"current_now()"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "date" type and use the [build in format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) **epoch_millis**

That means first change your mappings

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
     "_doc": {
        "properties": {
           "default_time": {
              "type":   "date",
              "format": "epoch_millis"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

and then set the current time in your client.

Comment: Is there any way to let Ed set it by default instead of we setting the time in defaults -time filed

Comment: We are looking for replica of now() of MySQL in elasticsearch while indexing that we should not care about it and let Es to handle this for us

Comment: I don't think so. From the link that you posted-- "you should populate a regular date field with the current timestamp on application side"